# Eastern European cartoon with a talking raven

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, animals, animation

I watched part of this cartoon. Judging by the style and the voice acting, I would say that it was probably made in the Soviet Union or one of the Eastern European countries. Anyways, one of the characters in that cartoon is a talking raven who introduces himself to some other character as Corvax, or maybe Corax, one of the two (It does reference the scientific name for the common raven). Any idea what this cartoon might be?

Comment: This does not seem blatantly on-topic. Can you please check [our policy on works featuring anthropomorphic animals](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/98028) to check whether it is, and edit your question to include the science-fiction or fantasy elements, if there are any?

Comment: You want the science fiction/ fantasy elements listed?  How about a talking raven for a start?

Comment: @Pete - if you have a look at the meta post Jenayah linked our current consensus is that a talking animal does not automatically make something on-topic

Comment: @fez looks like it is not just a talking bird but a sentient one.

Comment: @Yaroslav still going by that same meta post, a bunch of sentient anthropomorphic animals still isn't enough, by itself, to deem a work science-fiction or fantasy by our standards.

Comment: @User73910: Of course, all it would take for re-opening is you making an [edit] to your question to indicate "There was magic in the story" or "I'm pretty sure advanced technology was involved". :)

Comment: Talking animals aside,  Bjorn's answer of The Snow Queen looks like a likely candidate, very probably the correct answer. It's certainly fanasy. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @Pete - we should wait for a confirmation from the OP that it *is* The Snow Queen before reopening

Comment: And also, is that even board policy in the first place? It looks to me like its one person expressing an opinion, which several other people disagree with.

Comment: @fez The voice acting, the name of the raven, and the introduction scene look about right. I would say there's a very good chance that The Snow Queen is correct, though I'm not absolutely sure of it, so I would be interested in hearing if there are any other possibilities before accepting the current answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be the 1956 Soviet version of the [The Snow Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Snow_Queen_(1957_film))?
It was a retelling of H.C Andersens story of the same name, made in a classic eastern European style.
It also adds the character Mr. Corax, who is a talking raven.

[image: The snow queen in her palace]

The story is a quite straight retelling of the classic fairytale. The heroine Gerda searches for her lost friend who has been taken by the Snow Queen. After she traded her shoes to a river for help finding him she meets the talking raven

From Wikipedia

> Gerda is next found by the seashore where she is met by a raven, "Mr. Corax" (Ancient Greek for "raven"). Gerda tells him that she is looking for a "good, kind, brave boy". Mr. Corax tells her that such a boy is now living at the palace of a princess. Mr. Corax takes Gerda to the palace to find his fiancée Henrietta, who knows the palace and can guide Gerda through it. They arrive at the palace in the midst of a ball with fireworks. When all are asleep, the ravens take Gerda into the palace and to the royal bedroom. Gerda takes a lantern and tries to wake the boy, but he is not Kay and, startled, she drops the lantern. The shock awakens him and princess, who calls her guards. When the princess hears Gerda's tale of seeking her friend, she and the prince decide to help.

Comment: The name of the raven, the voice acting, and the intro scene in general seem about right, though I'm not absolutely sure about it. Would be interested in hearing if there are any other possibilities before accepting this answer.